# Bootstrap drop down list is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am following this link [bootstrap drop down menu](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonDropdowns) to create a drop down menu. When I click button, a drop down list appears and when I hover mouse over drop down menu only first two list items are click able, rest of the items are seem to be disable/not click able or some thing is going wrong. Here is the code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "teacher"))
{
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">E-portal
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    @*<div class="dropdown">
        *@
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Student", "Index", "Student")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teacher", "Index", "Teacher")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", "Department")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("University", "Index", "University")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Course Management", "Index", "Course")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Class Management", "Index", "Classes")</li>
        </ul>
        @*
    </div>
    *@                                     
</div>
}
```

Script:

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What should I do to get it work ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. All iteems seems to be enabled. [**See picture**](http://es.tinypic.com/r/svqvjk/8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `class=dropdown` DIV..

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">E-portal
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/t2GjUtK03P